# Wordpress plugin section does not show names of plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Today I opened one of my site and I found that Plugins are activated but their name are not displayed there.

[image]

And also I am  getting this error

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_pre_kses_block_attributes' not found or invalid function name in /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288

Comment: Have you recently change your PHP version or add any new Plugin?

Comment: No. Actually this is my clients site and don't know what he has done with the site

Comment: Try to change the THEME and check the page again if there is any code in `functions.php` which is making this issue then you can debug `functions.php` file. If it does not work then disable all the plugins from the Admin Dashboard and check it again. If it starts working then enable the plugin one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress Update solved this error

Answer (score 0):

Try deactivating all plugins then activate them one by one to figure out if one of the plugins is causing conflict.

Comment: Decativated plugins by renaming plugin folder but tit shows same error

Answer (score 0):

> So basically the cause of this could be that one of the plugins is not working properly.

- **What you can do**

> Deactivate all the plugins and activate them one by one.
>
> > - define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

Also the error you are getting is coming from one of the plugins